# Connecting Mobile Broadband and WIFI simultaneously on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, interface, broadband

OS Ubuntu 14.04.

Objective: wwan0 is my Broadband Connection - want to use to connect to intranet only (corporate network)

wlan0 is my WIFI connection - want to use to connect to internet only

I am using NM and able to connect to both networks simultaneously.

Problem:

1. When I check "Use this connection only for resources on its network" for WIFI (wlan0), I can only access intranet.

output of route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.103.6.66     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wwan0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
10.103.a.bc     *               255.255.255.192 U     13     0        0 wwan0
```

2. When I check "Use this connection only for resources on its network" for Mobile Broadband (wwan0), I can only access internet.

output of route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
10.103.d.ef     *               255.255.255.192 U     13     0        0 wwan0
```

How/What do I configure so that I can achieve my objective? viz, use WIFI for internet and Mobile BB for intranet

Comment: It is not clear what is your intranet. How do you connect there? Over internet too using broadband, or some more direct way. Are these corporate resources in some IP subnet?

Comment: intranet refers to corporate resources. I connect using mobile broadband (wwan0). For connection out of  the corporate network  into internet I use WIFI wlan0.

Comment: You need to add more details. What is your intranet IP subnet? You can set up a route there through wwan0. But you need to know the mask.

Comment: From NM Connection Info I get subnet mask for wwan0 is 255.255.255.248. ifconfig: wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:80:37:ec:02:00  
          inet addr:10.103.a.bcd  Bcast:10.103.9.167  Mask:255.255.255.248

Comment: And each time you get a different gateway on wwan0? That is weird. Do you work for a broadband company?

Comment: looks like it ... I connect to wwan0 only and now i see Default Route as 10.103.9.163

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27100/discussion-between-hmadhi-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and have met my objectives.

I am using the hint provided to me by Pilot6.

By using a script I am able to identify the default route that is assigned when connecting to wwan0 something like :

`IP=$(nmcli dev list iface ttyACM1 | awk '/gw =/ { print $7 }')`

I then use the default route to set routes for specific IP addresses on the intranet.

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw $IP
```

etc

All other traffic is then routed via wlan0.

Answer (score -1):

Well theoretically, you can't connect to two networks simultaneously. But there are tools like Connectify dispatcher that let you combine two connections.  Have a look [here](https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy)

Comment: In fact, it's a solution and the page isn't an article or a forum link, it's a repository in github. and thanks for the edit, i appreciate that Fabby :D